# Grails GORM vs MS ADO with Excel Datasource

Tags: grails

Morning All, Microsoft has different data access object to make you easy to connect and access your database. The old one is called DAO. The newer (still old) one is called ADO.  I think Grails calls its GORM.

One thing great about Microsoft's is that it can connect to an Excel file just like a database.  A sheet is a table. An Excel column is a database column.  Row is row.  You can use SQL statement to query the Excel file like `Select Sum(sheet1.column1) From sheet1 Where sheet1.column10 > 25 Group By sheet1.column 5` for example.

I am learning to use POI to access the Excel file.  So far so good.  I can do it no problem.  (I try the Grails Excel Import plugin but it keeps crashing.)  But basically, I am looping through the rows and columns and a bunch of if-then-else to access the data in the Excel file.

Can I connect to an Excel file as a datasource and run the dynamic finder to query the Excel file in Grails?

Danken!

Answer (score 0):

Since GORM is built upon Hibernate it should be possible to use an Excel file as a DataSource for Hibernate. Consult the Hibernate documentation on how to do so. Also [this article](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/excel-jdbc-hibernate.rst) may help give you some ideas on how to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it is too much for me.  I understand the workflow but I don't know how to apply it to Grails. Reading the article gives me some ideas.  In order to be able to use the Grails findBy*, I will need to read all the rows to create a list of domain objects locally in memory.  I don't know how to do this yet or if I am doing this correctly. It does not seem correct at this point because findBy* will look for the records in the database from what I understand.